# Java: convert a char[] to a CharSequence

Tags: java, string

What is the most direct and/or efficient way to convert a `char[]` into a `CharSequence`?

Comment: Just curious! Why do you need the CharSequence?

Comment: Because I'm writing to an Appendable.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Without the copy:

```
CharSequence seq = java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(array);
```

However, the `new String(array)` approach is likely to be easier to write, easier to read and faster.

Comment: I chose the most direct way.  yours is probably the most efficient, you can't have both i guess

Comment: Direct? More direct not to copy, surely? But the CharBuffer subclass code is probably less well exercised, so might end up being slower.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think CharBuffer.wrap will be slower? Just because the code is less mature? Surely if I'm doing this in a tight loop, I should prefer the copy-free version?

Comment: It's well known that going through NIO buffers can be a bit slow (there's an awful lot to inline, and that may not happen as you expect). OTOH, CharSequence is often slower the getChars.

Comment: This should have less overhead than a CharBuffer: https://gist.github.com/ncruces/ca9f91d89630d27ff05e35410a89022b

Comment: Not making a copy and not using a String is very important when dealing with char[] that happens to contain a password. So your CharBuffer.wrap solution works great in that case. I also don't see any speed issues when looking into the source code down this path either.

Comment: @tackline -- This answer is getting on to 10 years old now.  I'm wondering if you still think the CharBuffer is likely to be slower than copying the array into a String?

Comment: Also curious to know what your thoughts are @TomHawtin-tackline

Answer (score 10):

A `String` is a `CharSequence`.  So you can just create a new `String` given your `char[]`.

```
CharSequence seq = new String(arr);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Context:**

One of the most common usage of char[] instead of String, is to "temporary" store secrets/passwords. To pass it to initialization of some service/clients ... The sercrets are not needed after such initialization. But in java string is not possible to clear it from memory (manualy nor by garbage collection)... *So, it is basically forbiden to store secrets in Strings.*

Recommended way: Load secrets to char[], pass it to init proces, and clear it manually (set forEach char[i] = '0';).
Read about this problem on specialized blogs...

**Question/Answer:**

- if service/cliets API accepts only pass/secret as a string - don't use it (and report bug)
- if service/cliets API accept char array, use it and clear it
- if service/cliets API accept CharSequence, java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(array) could be used and cleared after

NOTE: unfortunately, one has to check even 3rd party service/client init source code, it happens that they convert char array to string somewhere deep in their code... )-: Choose your dependencies wisely.