# Most efficient way to convert a single char to a CharSequence

Tags: java, android, string, char, charsequence

What's the most efficient way to pass a single char to a method expecting a CharSequence?

This is what I've got:

```
textView.setText(new String(new char[] {c} ));
```

According to [the answers given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299606/java-convert-a-char-to-a-charsequence), this is a sensible way of doing it where the input is a character array. I was wondering if there was a sneaky shortcut I could apply in the single-char case.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(c))
```

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the implementation of the `Character.toString(char c)` method reveals that they use almost the same code you use:

```
  public String toString() {
       char buf[] = {value};
       return String.valueOf(buf);
  }
```

For readability, you should just use `Character.toString( c )`.

Another efficient way would probably be

```
new StringBuilder(1).append(c);
```

It's definitely more efficient that using the `+` operator because, according to the javadoc:

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the `StringBuilder`(or `StringBuffer`) class and its append method

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm going with the accepted answer as I suspect the String class probably has a built-in table of single-character Strings to support the valueOf() functionality efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

The most compact CharSequence you can get when you have a handful of chars is the CharBuffer.  To initialize this with your char value:

```
CharBuffer.wrap(new char[]{c});
```

That being said, using Strings is a fair bit more readable and easy to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Shorthand, as in fewest typed characters possible:

```
c+""; // where c is a char
```

In full:

```
textView.setText(c+"");
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution without concatenation is this:

```
Character.valueOf(c).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = 'y';
textView.setText(""+c);
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding to an answer mentioned above ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6603135/2227743)), adding an example to make things clearer

```
char c = 'a';
CharSequence cs = String.valueOf(c);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603135/2227743

Comment: @EricAya the answer you mention uses textView and setText whose meaning was not clear to me. Hence I made this example, just to make it clearer. 
I wanted to do this as a comment to original answer only, but I did not have enough reputation.

Let me just mention credit to the original answer

Comment: I understand your point of view. Still, `String.valueOf(c)` is the solution to OP's question, and it has already been suggested in the other answer. No need to post it again in my opinion.