# How to get character array from a CharSequence?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, charsequence

Is there any way to convert a `CharSequence` to an array of `char`s? Why doesn't the interface have a method to get characters as an array?

Comment: Probably because it was created before default methods existed and they didn't go back and add them.

Comment: (Not probably, definitely)

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299606/java-convert-a-char-to-a-charsequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first convert the `CharSequence` to `String` and then get it as character array:

```java
public char[] getAsCharArray(CharSequence input) {
    return input.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

Comment: Is it a way to do it w/o `toString()`? Assume char sequence contains a password.